# Playing HTML5 video from local

Tags: html, html5-video

I just learned [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/) that in order to play some video in HTML5's `<video>` tag I should make sure that while serving video on some URL appropriate `Content-Type` has also to be set.

How can this be avoided when I simply run my web page from local file system or I don't have ability to manipulate server response headers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet is to use [HTML5 FileReader API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/#dfn-filereader) ([tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-file-readingbyname)).
That will provide the local video as a url. In some sites you could find demo showing the previews of the images before upload, but by theory (and practical, see the link below) it is possible to use the same on audio and video.

I've done a small demo (not for this, but for the Camera API), which might suite your need.

see it yourself: http://jsbin.com/efunel/6

the video demo worked in chromium(20.0), and in firefox(16.0) (after taking REALLY long time!!!), with [Webm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webm) format only.

PS: try selecting a small video (below 15M).

EDIT: 
(code snippet as @headkit requested it)

```
fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function (event) {
    element.attr("src",event.target.result);
};
fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Comment: You can also use an element on the DOM and use the following snippet in the fileReader.onload function
domElement.innerHTML = '<p><video controls>' +
                        '<source src="' + event.target.result + '" type="video/mp4"/>' +
                        '</video></p>'

If you want a video that gives you controls provided you use a modern browser

Comment: @rax check the fiddle, the same is done here only without creating the DOM on-the-fly. the only difference is that it lacks controls, which can be fixed easily.

Comment: @Avinash Is there a way to get it to work for large file as well? Something like getting an URL that reference the file and setting it as video.src